# PostgreSQL schema upgrade issue during Thingsboard 3.3.2 to 3.6.1 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, thingsboard

#### Description:

I recently attempted to upgrade Thingsboard from version 3.3.2 to 3.6.1 following the official upgrade documentation. However, I encountered a problem during the upgrade process, specifically during the upgrade from version 3.3.2 to 3.4.0 where the PostgreSQL schema upgrade failed.

#### Issue Details:

**Current Version:** 3.3.2
**Target Version:** 3.6.1

**Problem Encountered:**
During the upgrade to version 3.4.0, the PostgreSQL schema upgrade fails, resulting in the following issue:

[could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]

#### Steps Taken:

1. Upgraded from version 3.3.2 to 3.4.0 as per the provided upgrade documentation.
2. Observed the failure during the PostgreSQL schema upgrade.

#### Expected Behavior:

Everything works smooth without any issue.

#### Additional Information:

- OS: Ubuntu
- PostgreSQL Version: 12.9
- Any relevant logs or error messages:

```
  ______    __      _                              ____                               __
 /_  __/   / /_    (_)   ____    ____ _   _____   / __ )  ____   ____ _   _____  ____/ /
  / /     / __ \  / /   / __ \  / __ `/  / ___/  / __  | / __ \ / __ `/  / ___/ / __  /
 / /     / / / / / /   / / / / / /_/ /  (__  )  / /_/ / / /_/ // /_/ /  / /    / /_/ /
/_/     /_/ /_/ /_/   /_/ /_/  \__, /  /____/  /_____/  \____/ \__,_/  /_/     \__,_/
                              /____/

 ===================================================
 :: ThingsBoard Professional Edition ::       (v3.5.0PE)
 ===================================================

Starting ThingsBoard Upgrade from version 3.4.4 ...
Clearing cache to upgrade from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0
Clearing cache [deviceProfiles]
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0 ...
Updating schema ...
Failed updating schema!!!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "entity_alarm" does not exist
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.loadSql(SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.java:873)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.upgradeDatabase(SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.java:703)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:270)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:66)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 3.5.0 to 3.5.0PE ...
Updating schema ...
relation "entity_group" already exists, skipping
relation "converter" already exists, skipping
relation "integration" already exists, skipping
relation "scheduler_event" already exists, skipping
relation "blob_entity" already exists, skipping
relation "role" already exists, skipping
relation "group_permission" already exists, skipping
relation "device_group_ota_package" already exists, skipping
relation "converter_debug_event" already exists, skipping
relation "integration_debug_event" already exists, skipping
relation "raw_data_event" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_entity_group_by_type_name_and_owner_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_converter_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_integration_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_role_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_entity_group_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_converter_debug_event_main" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_integration_debug_event_main" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_raw_data_event_main" already exists, skipping
Schema updated.
Installing SQL DataBase schema views and functions: schema-views-and-functions.sql
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column a.assignee_id does not exist
  Position: 3327
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.executeQueryFromFile(SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.java:97)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlEntityDatabaseSchemaService.createOrUpdateViewsAndFunctions(SqlEntityDatabaseSchemaService.java:68)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:274)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:66)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard upgrade failed!
```

#### Question:

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue during the upgrade from Thingsboard version 3.3.2 to 3.6.1, specifically during the PostgreSQL schema upgrade to version 3.4.0? If so, how did you resolve it, and are there any additional steps or considerations that I may have missed in the upgrade process?

[image]

We tried this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/cb37450470892f82a3787a1e989f3463295f1055/application/src/main/data/upgrade/3.4.4/schema_update.sql

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d thingsboard --file=schema_update.sql -W
```